# BDD on Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bdd

I am considering an approach fo BDD tests on Android.

The sample app — a simple messenger — has been made in Kotlin, so will be the tests.

I ended up with something like this :

```
class IGotYourMessage : Scenario<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity::class.java, {

    Given()
        .iAmOnLoginScreen()
    .When()
        .iLogin()
    .Then()
        .iSeeContactsList()
        .iSeeAContact()
    .When()
        .iSelectAContact()
    .Then()
        .iSeeMessagesList()
        .iSeeAMessage()
    .With(hashMapOf(
        "email" to "john@doe.com",
        "password" to "foo",
        "contactFirstName" to "Jane",
        "contactLastName" to "Doe",
        "messageText" to "Hello John!"
    ))
    .With(hashMapOf(
        "email" to "jane@doe.com",
        "password" to "bar",
        "contactFirstName" to "John",
        "contactLastName" to "Doe",
        "messageText" to "Hello John!"
    ))
})
```

I ended up with this assessment :

- The Given is a start state
- The When is an action
- The Then is an end state
- The Then is also a start state for the next action

So I can Given -> When -> Then -> When -> Then.

---

Each `With` is a test case providing its own data.

Each "step" is an extension on the `Given`, `When` or `Then` classes as in:

```
fun Then.iSeeAContact() {
    add({
        (it["contactFirstName"] as String).canSee()
        (it["contactLastName"] as String).canSee()
    })
    return this
}
```

The `canSee` method is an extension on `String`, using [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html):

```
fun String.canSee(): String {
    onView(withText(this)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    return this
}
```

So! I am here to get feedback, criticism and/or suggestions.

*This question was originally posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225380/bdd-on-android-with-kotlin)*